# Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined) SANITY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is the error I get when I try to open my product [image: This is the problem I get]

Basically it says it can't render an image URL that I'm trying to get from sanity database, but in the tutorial I am watching is working fine to him. My question is, is there a way to fix this error I get, because it is my first time with this error and I'm so confused
Here is my code:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { client, urlFor } from '../../lib/client';

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
  const { image, name, details, price } = product ?? {};

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product-detail-container">
        <div>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img src={urlFor(image && image[0])} />
          </div>
          <div className="small-images-container">
            {image?.map((item, i) => (
              <img
              src={urlFor(item)}
              className=""
              onMouseEnter=""
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"] {
    slug {
      current
    }
  }
  `;

  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: { 
      slug: product.slug.current
    }
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug }}) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
  const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]'
  
  const product = await client.fetch(query);
  const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

  console.log(product);

  return {
    props: { products, product }
  }
}

export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: You seem to have `undefined` values in the `product.image` array. Try filtering them out before rendering the `<img>`, e.g. `image?.filter(Boolean).map(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `url()` method on the `urlFor` call:

```
{image?.map((item, i) => (
  <img
  src={urlFor(item).url()}
  className=""
  onMouseEnter=""
  />
))}
```

Also, as stated in the comments, it would be a good idea to filter any possible `undefined` values on the `image` array.